# Touchpad not working with Ubuntu 17.10 on ASUS GL753V

Tags: touchpad

My touchpad is not working after upgrading to Ubuntu 17.10 (it does not even show up in mouse/touchpad dialog) from 17.04.

I know I'm not giving enough information, please tell me what information is needed.

`xinput` gives:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Asus Keyboard                             id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳  USB OPTICAL MOUSE                        id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam: USB2.0 HD           id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus WMI hotkeys                          id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus Keyboard                             id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ JABRA Jabra UC VOICE 550 MS mono USB      id=17   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Laptop is an ASUS GL753V

Comment: I have the same problem with Asus X541U. Did you find any solution?

Comment: hm if I log in to an Xorg session my touchpad is working. So it may be a bug with Wayland.

Comment: Not found a solution yet.

Comment: log in to an Xorg session my touchpad is working. It is a Wayland bug.

Comment: Same problem on ASUS GL703VD

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me: I stuck in and booted the version that was already on my USB drive then I quit the installation (though I will go to that version mine went to 17.04) (thought it erased everything but it didn't) and I unplugged the USB drive and restarted my laptop. It kept 17.10, but I guess reinstalled the correct drive for my touchpad to fully work again.

I have a Toshiba laptop but I'm pretty sure this method won't be limited to the brand of laptop.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found [here](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/touchpad-not-working-ubuntu-17-10/15359) works for me:

> Ubuntu MATE 17.10 is the first version to use the libinput touchpad driver by default instead of the older synaptics driver. Some touchpads still seem to work better with synaptics, so you could try installing it to see if that helps:
>
> `sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`
>
> and reboot to use it.